# Swift: how to make array of mutable dictionaries?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I set up an array of dictionaries to act as a basic dataset, and I would like to make updates for each `item` in the array. Here's my data:

```
var data: [[String: AnyObject]] = [
    [
        "name": "Item 1",
        "message": ""
    ],
    [
        "name": "Item 2",
        "message": ""
    ]
    //, ...
]
```

...and I want to update the message for each of the items:

```
for item in data {
    item["message"] = "Hello"
}
```

This throws the error:

> @lvalue $T5' is not identical to '(String, AnyObject)

...and I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) this is because each dictionary is immutable, right?

So I'm wondering, what is the best way to indicate that the dictionaries inside the array should be mutable?

Comment: The dictionaries in your `data` array *are* mutable, but `item` in the for-loop is not. The answers to the linked-to questions show different solutions to the problem.

Comment: Note, when reading that other question, that the accepted answer does _not_ answer this question (it goes on a tangent, mostly due to some other aspects of the question – this question would be a better candidate).  The second one down does answer what is being asked here more directly.